# MinGW Make causing StackDumps

Tags: makefile, mingw

When I use a unix utility from MinGW make, I get a StackDump file:

**error:**

```
sed -i -e 's/reveal.js\/css\/theme\/simple.css/reveal.js\/css\/theme\/moon.css/' index.html
      0 [main] sed 8744 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to sed.exe.stackdump
make: *** [index.html] Error 5
```

**sed.exe.stackdump:**

```
MSYS-1.0.12 Build:2012-07-05 14:56
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=68008DAA
eax=03019001 ebx=60EA4124 ecx=00692788 edx=00000150 esi=00000000 edi=60EA00D4
ebp=0028FE9C esp=0028FE78 program=c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sed.exe
cs=0023 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
0028FE9C  68008DAA  (60EA00D4, 00000150, 0028FEEC, 680044EA)
0028FEEC  6800466B  (00000000, 00000000, 0028FF2C, 00517CF8)
0028FF0C  68004C5F  (00401C28, 00000000, 5C952BA0, FFFFE001)
0028FF2C  68004C98  (00000000, 00000000, 928A67BF, FFFFF800)
0028FF5C  00517C08  (00401C28, FFFFE001, 00000001, 00000000)
0028FF8C  0040103D  (7FFDE000, 0028FFDC, 771F0BBB, 7FFDE000)
0028FF98  74F6919F  (7FFDE000, 99B8EAFE, 00000000, 00000000)
0028FFDC  771F0BBB  (FFFFFFFF, 771DC9D0, 00000000, 00000000)
0028FFEC  771F0B91  (00401000, 7FFDE000, 00000000, 78746341)
End of stack trace
```

I get very similar errors when trying to use tools like `rm`, `mv`, and `cp`. What can I do to fix these errors? It is making developing on Windows impossible.

The make binary that I am using is located at `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe`, and the version information is:

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i686-pc-msys
```

Comment: Which version of `make` are you using?  Are you using the version included with msysgit (and installed in `c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`)? Or the MSYS version? Or the native Windows version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing your problem is the msysgit version of `sed` is using the version of the MSYS DLL in `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin` instead of the DLL in `c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`. Try changing your `PATH` so that your makefile uses the `sed` in `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin`, rather than the msysgit version.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered the problem. I was actually using the MSYS version of make, but the `sed` binary was the one that shipped with cmder. This mismatch was causing the stackdumps. I fixed the path, and now it is working fine.