# Make.exe giving me a STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: makefile, stack-dump, nintendo-3ds

So, I'm trying to compile a homebrew program for the 3DS but when ever I run "make" I get this:

```
E:\3DS-Stuff\fasthax>make
  0 [main] make 16616 handle_exceptions: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
321 [main] make 16616 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to make.exe.stackdump
```

So then I found these links:
[MinGW Make causing StackDumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478026/mingw-make-causing-stackdumps)
https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/25
https://devkitpro.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2182

but they didn't help either so I decided to create a thread of my own.
This is my Stackdump:

```
MSYS-1.0.17 Build:2011-04-24 23:39
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=6085A9DA
eax=60E926C4 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=60E926C8 esi=0062E6E0 edi=6E6F6874
ebp=0062EAE8 esp=0062D6D0 program=C:\Users\wg\Downloads\Devkitpro\msys\bin\make.exe
cs=0023 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
0062EAE8  6085A9DA  (00000000, 0062EB50, 6E6F6874, 100240D8)
0062EB18  6085CDB6  (00000000, 00000003, 0062EB50, 6E6F6874)
0062EB38  6080E236  (0062EB50, 6E6F6874, 0062EB68, 6080E236)
0062EF68  60882726  (79502F63, 6E6F6874, 332D3533, 2F3A2F32)
4547638 [main] make 16616 handle_exceptions: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
4643619 [main] make 16616 handle_exceptions: Error while dumping state (probably corrupted stack)
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: You're using a fairly outdated build of msys, you should look into installing [msys2](https://msys2.github.io/), you might find the crash simply disappears.

Comment: Thanks it works :D.